# Unit-test a controller that has a Dependency Injection in MVC

Tags: unit-testing

I am trying to unit test a controller that already has a constructor dependency injection. How do I also pass the dependency injection to the unit test? I am using the Ninject to do the DI in the controller but I have never unit tested anything so this is new for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you pass constructor dependencies manually from your unit test.  This allows you to test a small piece of your software by passing in mocks or doubles of the dependencies.  We have a fairly large system and have never needed to use our injection framework for a unit test.

The injection framework is used for production and for integration tests where you are wiring together many components.

Comment: yes, but sometimes if your controller has a large constructor that relies on dependency injection, you wouldnt want to have to pass in the same mocked services over and over for each test.  IT would be nice to inject the default mocked services for each controller and then user named parameters for the services that you would actually be testing.